# XSL Template Working for Tag but Not Attribute

Tags: html, xslt-2.0

I have a template that replaces **\n** **\r** and **actual new lines**  with **<br />**:

```
<!-- convert \n and \r to <br /> and preserve real line breaks -->
    <xsl:template name="lineBreak">
        <xsl:param name="field" select="."/>
        <!-- current element of no value is specified -->
        <xsl:variable name="br">
            <br/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="nl">\\n</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="cr">\\r</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name='newline'>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$field" regex="{$cr}|{$nl}|{$newline}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:sequence select="$br"/>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

I am calling the template like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="lineBreak">
<xsl:with-param name="field" select="artist"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:call-template name="lineBreak">
<xsl:with-param name="field" select="artist/@initials"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

I am using this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist initials="L1:BD \nL2:line2 
        L3:line 3">Bob Dylan \rIs cool
        LINE 3</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist initials="BT">Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

You can see from the output that it is replacing  everything correctly except for real new lines in the attributes.  every "L3" or "LINE 3" is produced by a "real New Line" not a "\n" or "\r".

[image]

HTML Output:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Initials</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Empire Burlesque</td>
                <td>Bob Dylan <br>Is cool<br>       LINE 3</td>
                <td>L1:BD <br>L2:line2    L3:line 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hide your heart</td>
                <td>Bonnie Tyler</td>
                <td>BT</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us minimal but complete samples of the XSLT to reproduce that. Also show the wanted and current transformation result as code samples, not only as pictures.

Comment: Updated with requested info of  html output and additional template info

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to occur due to [Attribute-Value Normalization](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-xml-19980210#AVNormalize):

> Before the value of an attribute is passed to the application or checked for validity, the XML processor must normalize it as follows:
>
> - a character reference is processed by appending the referenced character to the attribute value
> - an entity reference is processed by recursively processing the replacement text of the entity
> - **a whitespace character (#x20, #xD, #xA, #x9) is processed by appending #x20 to the normalized value, except that only a single #x20 is appended for a "#xD#xA" sequence that is part of an external parsed entity or the literal entity value of an internal parsed entity**
> - other characters are processed by appending them to the normalized value
>
> If the declared value is not CDATA, then the XML processor must further process the normalized attribute value by discarding any leading and trailing space (#x20) characters, and by replacing sequences of space (#x20) characters by a single space (#x20) character.
>
> All attributes for which no declaration has been read should be treated by a non-validating parser as if declared CDATA.

So the attribute value is "normalized" before being processed by your template. This means that the line-break is converted to a `#x20` space before it could be matched by your RegEx. You can verify that by executing only the *identity template*.

I don't know of any workarounds.

Comment: is there a "don't' normalize this field "  option or something?

Comment: The "workaround" is the first item of the list: "a character reference is processed by appending the referenced character to the attribute value". That way `&#10;` in the attribute value markup is parsed into a newline character.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: You're right, but that approach would include changing the source XML, wouldn't it?

Comment: @zx485, yes, that is true, if the XML input doesn't follow the rules you have cited to ensure it inserts any wanted newlines as character references your paragraph cited in bold rules and certainly any XSLT working later on the normalized value only has spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "real" line break in an attribute value you need to mark it up as a character reference e.g. `att="Line 1.&#10;Line2"`, that way the attribute value should contain a line break. Not every parser might implement that but as you tagged the question as XSLT 2.0 I assume it is Saxon probably on the Java platform and that way I think you usually have an underlying XML parser that can deal with character references in attribute values as the spec asks for.

However, that approach is kind of brittle as any parsing/serialization/editing step to your XML might involve a parser/serializer/editor that doesn't preserve your character reference.